# Creating Java patterns

Tags: java

A java program that displays a pattern according to the user’s input.

This is my desired program:

Input:

```
3
3
1
2
```

Output:

```
###
   \
    \
     \
     /
    /_
```

The problem is it’s not showing my desired output.When I entered an input, this is what displays:

Input:

```
3
3
2
1
```

Output:

```
###
   \
    \
     \
   /
  /_
```

Can you help me fix this? The problem is on num3. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{   
public static void main(String args[])  {   
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
 
int i;   
int num1=input.nextInt();
int num2= input.nextInt();
int num3=input.nextInt();
int num4=input.nextInt();

    //num1
    for(i=0; i<num1; i++) {   
        System.out.print("# ");   
    }  

    //num2
    for(int b=1; b<=num2; b++){
        System.out.println();
        
        for (int j=1; j<=num2; j++){
            if(b==j || j==b){
                System.out.print(" ".repeat(num1*2 -1) + "\\");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
        
    // num3
    for(i = 0; i < num3; i++){
        System.out.println();
        
        for(int j = 0; j < num3; j++) {
            if(i+j == num3 -1)
                System.out.print(" ".repeat(num1*2 - 2) + "/");
            else if( i != num3-1)
                System.out.print(" ");
        }        
    }
    
    //num4
    for(i=0; i<num4; i++) {   
        System.out.print("_");   
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this code solves your problem.

Also, there is a mistake in the question. The first input should be 3,3,2,1 and not 3,3,1,2. It is a little misleading.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{   
public static void main(String args[])  {   
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
 
int i;   
int num1=input.nextInt();
int num2= input.nextInt();
int num3=input.nextInt();
int num4=input.nextInt();

    //num1
    for(i=0; i<num1; i++) {   
        System.out.print("# ");   
    }  

    //num2
    for(int b=1; b<=num2; b++){
        System.out.println();
        
        for (int j=1; j<=num2; j++){
            if(b==j || j==b){
                System.out.print(" ".repeat(num1*2 -1) + "\\");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
        
    // num3
    for(i = 0; i < num3; i++){
        System.out.println();
        
        for(int j = 0; j < num3; j++) {
            if(i+j == num3 -1)
                System.out.print(" ".repeat(num1*2) + "/");
                //Changed from repeat(num1*2-2)
            else if( i != num3-1)
                System.out.print(" ");
        }        
    }
    
    //num4
    for(i=0; i<num4; i++) {   
        System.out.print("_");   
    }    
  }
}
```